# asp.net HyperLinkField Has no ToolTip property (Alt text)

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, tooltip

I wish there was a ToolTip field in HyperLinkField as there is one in HyperLink.
I'm creating a HyperLinkField by code before binding to my data source:

```
HyperLinkField hl = new HyperLinkField(); 
hl.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { "col" };
hl.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "{0}";
hl.DataTextField = "Foo";
```

Is there any way to also set a value to something which will render as a tooltip (or alt text)?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's correct, there's no tooltip/alt text property in a **[HyperlinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield_properties.aspx)**. To get around this shortcoming, you need to use a template field and add a regular Hyperlink control.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Href">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#
          Eval("Href") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Href") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Text")         %>'> 
       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, doing this in a programmatic requires a lot of work. You need to create your own class that implements the **[ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx)** interface. Here's a **[tutorial](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609991)** on that.

Comment: When you copy code off of a web page, you should be providing a link to that web page.

Answer (score 7):

Your requirement can be accompished in `<asp:HyperlinkField>` itself by adding tooltip for that specific cell in `RowDataBound` event of a `GridView`. After binding the GridView to your DataSource you can do this in a `RowDataBound` event as follows:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = "Your tooltip text";
}
```

Though you have accepted another answer, my answer may be helpful for some other users!